# R: delete attribute in a slot of a SpatialPixelsDataFrame object

Tags: r, attributes, slots

I want to plot my kriging-results which are stored in a SpatialPixelsDataFrame object. Using spplot, it automatically creates a plot including var1.pred, var1.var and var1.stdev.

This is nice, but I want the spplot function to only plot var1.pred, which is why I want to delete var1.var and var1.stdev (they are stored as attributes in the slot @data).

I don't know how to do this - can anybody help? Thanks in advance!

Let's say my object is called "aa", then here is the information about it:

```
str(aa)
Formal class 'SpatialPixelsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 7 slots
 ..@ data       :'data.frame':  4986 obs. of  3 variables:
 .. ..$ var1.pred : num [1:4986] 5.95 5.96 5.96 5.94 5.95 ...
 .. ..$ var1.var  : num [1:4986] 0.000445 0.0005 0.00072 0.008354 0.000917 ...
 .. ..$ var1.stdev: num [1:4986] 0.0211 0.0224 0.0268 0.0914 0.0303 ...
 ..@ coords.nrs : int [1:2] 1 2
 ..@ grid       :Formal class 'GridTopology' [package "sp"] with 3 slots
 .. .. ..@ cellcentre.offset: Named num [1:2] 0.139 0.408
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "x1" "x2"
 .. .. ..@ cellsize         : Named num [1:2] 0.174 0.174
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "x1" "x2"
 .. .. ..@ cells.dim        : Named int [1:2] 56 154
 .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "x1" "x2"
 ..@ grid.index : int [1:4986] 8604 8548 8492 8435 8436 8379 8380 8323 8324 8325 ...
 ..@ coords     : num [1:4986, 1:2] 6.22 6.22 6.22 6.05 6.22 ...
 .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 .. .. ..$ : NULL
 .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x1" "x2"
 ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] 0.139 0.408 9.697 26.994
 .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x1" "x2"
 .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"
 ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slots
 .. .. ..@ projargs: chr NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Please next time provide a [reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and no need to delete something here.

In the help file of `spplot` you have

> ```
>   spplot.grid(obj, zcol = names(obj), ..., names.attr, scales = list(draw = FALSE),
>   xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, aspect = mapasp(obj,xlim,ylim),
>   panel = panel.gridplot, sp.layout = NULL, formula, xlim = bbox(obj)[1, ],
>   ylim = bbox(obj)[2, ], checkEmptyRC = TRUE)
>
> ....................................................................
> ....................................................................
> ....................................................................
>
>  obj: object of class extending Spatial-class
>
> zcol: character; attribute name(s) or column number(s) in attribute
>       table
> ....................................................................
> ....................................................................
> ....................................................................
> ```

When you get stuck in R, the first thing to try is the help file first. 
Here you could have seen that the `zcol` parameters can solve you problem.

Using the `meuse.grid` dataset which have 5 columns, we can decide to plot the "soil" column like this

```
require(sp)
data(meuse.grid) 
coordinates(meuse.grid) = c("x", "y") 
gridded(meuse.grid) <- TRUE

class(meuse.grid)
[1] "SpatialPixelsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"

names(meuse.grid)
[1] "part.a" "part.b" "dist"   "soil"   "ffreq" 

spplot(meuse.grid, "soil")
```

This one will work too

```
spplot(meuse.grid["soil"])
```

Answer (score 0):

a@data is a data.frame, so you can maniplate it like a dataframe:

```
a@data<-a@data[,1,drop=FALSE]
```

The drop=FALSE parameter makes [] not try to reduce the result to the least dimensionality.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the plot name:

```
split(dataset["vari.pred"])
```